# pdfbox for pdf creation: how to do the text layout?

Tags: java, maven, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I want to create a PDF using pdfbox (https://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/documentcreation.html). However, pdfbox does not seem to provide dynamic text layout mechanisms like those a text editor like OpenOffice provides (automatic text flow using predefined text formattings like block format, centered text, line breaks etc.).

Is there any Java library that provides that functionality on top of pdfbox or separate from it? Or do you have any free code available?

Comment: I'd recommend iText if you want to do this in Java or FOP if you prefer XSL-T.

Comment: No, not at this time. Feel free to contribute something :-)

Comment: hmmm. would be better to have something independent of the output format. and then create an adapter or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, that's why I started [PDFBox-Layout](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout). It has support for simple word wrapping, text and paragraph alignment, pagination, vertical and column layout, and markup for easy bold/italic highlighting.

See the [Wiki](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/wiki) for more information. Maybe you will find it useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

[BlockFrame](https://github.com/gingerdroids/BlockFrame) (on GitHub) is another layout framework for PDFBox, filling a different space to PDFBox-Layout. PDFBox-Layout seems oriented to text, but BlockFrame is designed for complex data structures. It's also designed with extensibility in mind.

I needed something to print crosswords I'd generated, and wound up coding a framework. If there's interest, I'll extend and maintain it. It should be possible to use BlockFrame to draw small, complex sections of larger PDF documents, as well as generate an entire PDF.

Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend that you use "Apache PDFBox" instead of "PDF Box" on your github page so that your project gets found easier. Also consider to add examples (screenshots).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Ruby. I used Prawn in the past, which has a syntax similar to pdfbox. Lots of primitives.

I found it was a lot better to use a HTML+CSS to PDF solution. I'm already generating HTML and CSS, and it's easy to make print-specific CSS. Then I use either wkhtmltopdf or princexml to generate PDF. Both are command-line tools that run on a variety of platforms.

Comment: HTML has no concept of page breaks. That's of course no show stopper for many purposes, but some.

Comment: That's incorrect. Of course HTML+CSS has a concept of page breaks. There's page-break-before and page-break-after, and a handful of other controls. There's even widow and orphan control. I was able to layout an entire novel in HTML, and then use PrinceXML to convert it to PDF.